# How to make links in the CSS

Tags: css

I found and I integrated this code in my Wordpress.
I would ask you, do you know how to make links in the CSS and where?

I made the links with `<a href="">` in the HTML but then I have links only on the text and not on the whole button.

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato");

*,
*:before,
*:after { /* Slow, yes I know :) */
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  font-family: Lato, Sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  background: #353138;
  background: -moz-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover,  #353138 0%, #1a181c 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(radial, center center, 0px, center center, 100%, color-stop(0%, #353138), color-stop(100%, #1a181c));
  background: -webkit-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover,  #353138 0%,#1a181c 100%);
  background: -o-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover,  #353138 0%,#1a181c 100%);
  background: -ms-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover,  #353138 0%,#1a181c 100%);
  background: radial-gradient(ellipse at center,  #353138 0%,#1a181c 100%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr = '#353138', endColorstr='#1a181c', GradientType=1);
}
.container {
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 20px;
  -webkit-perspective: 1500px;
  -moz-perspective: 1500px;
  -ms-perspective: 1500px;
  perspective: 1500px;
  position: relative;
}
.toggle {
  color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 16px;
  font-size: 20px;
  float: left;
}
.menu {
  margin: 100px auto;
  position: relative;
  background: #62278d;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #62278d 0%, #2cc09b 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#62278d), color-stop(100%,#2cc09b));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #62278d 0%,#2cc09b 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #62278d 0%,#2cc09b 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #62278d 0%,#2cc09b 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #62278d 0%,#2cc09b 100%);
  width: 300px;
  border-width: 20px 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #fff;
  color: #fff;
  height: 540px;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
     -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
      -ms-transform-style: preserve-3d;
          transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
     -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
       -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
          transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 50px 0 #444;
     -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 50px 0 #444;
          box-shadow: 0 0 50px 0 #444;
}
input.toggle:checked ~ .menu {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-200px) translateZ(-150px) rotateX(45deg) rotateZ(45deg);
     -moz-transform: translateY(-150px) rotateX(45deg) rotateZ(45deg);
      -ms-transform: translateY(-150px) rotateX(45deg) rotateZ(45deg);
       -o-transform: translateY(-150px) rotateX(45deg) rotateZ(45deg);
          transform: translateY(-150px) rotateX(45deg) rotateZ(45deg);
}
.menu:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  height: 30px;
  width: 300px;
  top: 520px;
  left: 0px;
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(90deg) translateY(-15px) translateZ(15px);
     -moz-transform: rotateX(90deg) translateY(-15px) translateZ(15px);
      -ms-transform: rotateX(90deg) translateY(-15px) translateZ(15px);
       -o-transform: rotateX(90deg) translateY(-15px) translateZ(15px);
          transform: rotateX(90deg) translateY(-15px) translateZ(15px);
  background: #fff;
  pointer-events: none;
}
.menu:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  height: 540px;
  width: 30px;
  top: -20px;
  right: -30px;
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(90deg) translateZ(-15px) translateX(15px);
     -moz-transform: rotateY(90deg) translateZ(-15px) translateX(15px);
      -ms-transform: rotateY(90deg) translateZ(-15px) translateX(15px);
       -o-transform: rotateY(90deg) translateZ(-15px) translateX(15px);
          transform: rotateY(90deg) translateZ(-15px) translateX(15px);
  border-width: 20px 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #fff;
  background: #62278d;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #62278d 0%, #2cc09b 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#62278d), color-stop(100%,#2cc09b));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #62278d 0%,#2cc09b 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #62278d 0%,#2cc09b 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #62278d 0%,#2cc09b 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #62278d 0%,#2cc09b 100%);
  pointer-events: none;
}
.menu .top {
  padding: 15px 15px 15px 20px;
  width: 100%;
}
.menu .top .search {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
.menu .top .search input {
  background-color: transparent;
  -webkit-transition: all 100ms ease-in-out;
     -moz-transition: all 100ms ease-in-out;
      -ms-transition: all 100ms ease-in-out;
       -o-transition: all 100ms ease-in-out;
          transition: all 100ms ease-in-out;
  color: transparent;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 20px;
  padding: 10px 30px 10px 15px;
  outline: 0 none;
  width: 60px;
  height: 40px;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(1px);
     -moz-transform: translateZ(1px);
      -ms-transform: translateZ(1px);
       -o-transform: translateZ(1px);
          transform: translateZ(1px);
  z-index: 2;
}
.menu .top .search input:focus {
  width: 200px;
  color: #fff;
}
.menu .top .search:after {
  content: '\f002';
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  font-size: 16px;
  position: absolute;
  color: #fff;
  top: 11px;
  right: 18px;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  pointer-events: none;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(1px);
     -moz-transform: translateZ(1px);
      -ms-transform: translateZ(1px);
       -o-transform: translateZ(1px);
          transform: translateZ(1px);
  z-index: 1;
}
.menu .top .exit {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  outline: 0 none;
  float: right;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(1px);
     -moz-transform: translateZ(1px);
      -ms-transform: translateZ(1px);
       -o-transform: translateZ(1px);
          transform: translateZ(1px);
  z-index: 2;
}
.menu .top .exit:focus,
.menu .top .exit:active {
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 20px;
}
.menu .top .exit:before {
  content: '';
  pointer-events: none;
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  top: 14px;
  left: -6px;
  border-width: 0 2px 0 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #fff;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
     -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
      -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
       -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
          transform: rotate(-45deg);
  z-index: 1;
}
.menu .top .exit:after {
  content: '';
  pointer-events: none;
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  top: -6px;
  left: -6px; 
  border-width: 0 2px 0 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #fff;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
     -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
      -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
       -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
          transform: rotate(45deg);
}
.menu .middle {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 40px;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 15px;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
     -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
      -ms-transform-style: preserve-3d;
          transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
.menu .middle li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 15px 0 15px 40px;
  outline: 0 none;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
     -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
      -ms-transform-style: preserve-3d;
          transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(1px);
     -moz-transform: translateZ(1px);
      -ms-transform: translateZ(1px);
       -o-transform: translateZ(1px);
          transform: translateZ(1px);
  z-index: 1;
}
.menu .middle li:hover {
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 80px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
     -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 80px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
          box-shadow: inset 0 0 80px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
  cursor: pointer;
}
.menu .middle li:hover:before,
.menu .middle li:focus:before {
  content: '\f0da';
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  font-size: 16px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  left: 20px;
}
.menu .middle li:focus,
.menu .middle li:focus:after {
  color: #3EAC9E;
  background-color: #62278d;
}
.menu .middle li .fa {
  padding-right: 15px;
}
.menu .middle li:focus:after,
.menu .middle li:hover:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  height: 48px;
  width: 30px;
  top: 0px;
  right: -30px;
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(90deg) translateZ(-14px) translateX(15px);
     -moz-transform: rotateY(90deg) translateZ(-14px) translateX(15px);
      -ms-transform: rotateY(90deg) translateZ(-14px) translateX(15px);
       -o-transform: rotateY(90deg) translateZ(-14px) translateX(15px);
          transform: rotateY(90deg) translateZ(-14px) translateX(15px);
  pointer-events: none;
  
}
.menu .middle li:hover:after {
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 80px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
     -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 80px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
          box-shadow: inset 0 0 80px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
}
.menu .bottom {
  height: 40px;
}
.menu-back {
  position: absolute;
  background: transparent;
  top: -20px;
  left: 0;
  width: 300px;
  height: 540px;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(-29px);
     -moz-transform: translateZ(-29px);
      -ms-transform: translateZ(-29px);
       -o-transform: translateZ(-29px);
          transform: translateZ(-29px);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 100px 100px 50px -30px #111;
     -moz-box-shadow: 100px 100px 50px -30px #111;
          box-shadow: 100px 100px 50px -30px #111;
  z-index: 0;
}
.glass-reflection {
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-transition: box-shadow 1s;
     -moz-transition: box-shadow 1s;
      -ms-transition: box-shadow 1s;
       -o-transition: box-shadow 1s;
          transition: box-shadow 1s;
  -webkit-transform: rotateZ(-1deg) translateZ(1px) skewY(60deg);
     -moz-transform: rotateZ(-1deg) translateZ(1px) skewY(60deg);
      -ms-transform: rotateZ(-1deg) translateZ(1px) skewY(60deg);
       -o-transform: rotateZ(-1deg) translateZ(1px) skewY(60deg);
          transform: rotateZ(-1deg) translateZ(1px) skewY(60deg);
  
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px -40px 0px -50px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.0);
     -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px -40px 0px -50px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.0);
          box-shadow: inset 0px -40px 0px -50px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.0);
  border-radius: 200px 0 20px 0 ;
  top: 85px;
  left: 95px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: transparent;
}
input.toggle:checked ~ .menu .glass-reflection {
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px -40px 150px -50px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15);
     -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px -40px 150px -50px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15);
          box-shadow: inset 0px -40px 150px -50px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15);
}
```

```html
<!--
Inspired by this dribble by The Purple Bunny:
https://dribbble.com/shots/1677163-Menu
-->
<div class="container">
  <input type="checkbox" class="toggle" id="toggle" checked="checked" /><label class="toggle" for="toggle"> Toggle tilt</label>
  <div class="menu">
    <div class="top">
      <span class="search">
        <input type="text">
      </span>
      <a class="exit" href="#" tabindex="0"></a>
    </div>
    <ul class="middle">
      <li tabindex="0"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>Calendar</li>
      <li tabindex="0"><i class="fa fa-camera"></i>Photos</li>
      <li tabindex="0"><i class="fa fa-check-square-o"></i>Tasks</li>
      <li tabindex="0"><i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i>Places</li>
      <li tabindex="0"><i class="fa fa-codepen"></i>Codepen</li>
      <li tabindex="0"><i class="fa fa-dribbble"></i>Dribbble</li>
      <li tabindex="0"><i class="fa fa-user"></i>User account</li>
      <li tabindex="0"><i class="fa fa-cogs"></i>Settings</li>
    </ul>
    <div class="bottom"></div>
    <div class="menu-back"></div>
    <div class="glass-reflection"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your code doesn't demonstrate the issue

Comment: `<a href="">`  `<button>Button</button>` `</a>`

Comment: Links cannot contain buttons and buttons cannot contain links. It's invalid HTML

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried styling your link to look like a button? Like this?

```
a{border:solid 1px black; padding:20px;background-color:yellow; text-decoration:none;font-size:1.5em; border-radius:50%;}
```

I made padding big so you can put mouse all around the text inside of the button and see that it still works.

https://codepen.io/susanwinters/pen/wvWjBYW

Answer (score -1):

Wrap whole button with  tag, not only text.